# Как изменить размер картинки в picturebox через textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Не могу найти как можно изменять размер изображения picturebox через textbox, необходимо чтоб изменялась только  картинка по размеру а не сам элемент. Кто-нибудь знает как это делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Менять нужно размер самого изображения. Я это делаю, вызывая конструктор с оригинальным изображением и новыми шириной и высотой: `Bitmap(original, width, height)`.

Важно! Не забывайте освобождать ресурсы. При каждом изменении размера генерируется новая картинка. Предыдущую нужно удалить. Для этого вызываем `Dispose`.

Если будете менять оригинальное изображение (через `OpenFileDialog`, например), то обязательно нужно диспозить ранее загруженное изображение: `original.Dispose`.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        PictureBox pictureBox;
        NumericUpDown numericUpDownWidth;
        NumericUpDown numericUpDownHeight;
        Bitmap original;
        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            pictureBox = new PictureBox { Parent = this, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, Size = new Size(150, 150) };
            original = SystemIcons.Hand.ToBitmap();
            pictureBox.Image = (Bitmap)original.Clone();

            numericUpDownWidth = new NumericUpDown { Parent = this, Top = pictureBox.Bottom + 20, Minimum = 1 };
            numericUpDownHeight = new NumericUpDown { Parent = this, Top = pictureBox.Bottom + 50, Minimum = 1 };

            numericUpDownWidth.Value = original.Width;
            numericUpDownHeight.Value = original.Height;

            numericUpDownWidth.ValueChanged += NumericUpDown_ValueChanged;
            numericUpDownHeight.ValueChanged += NumericUpDown_ValueChanged;
        }

        private void NumericUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox.Image?.Dispose();
            int width = (int)numericUpDownWidth.Value;
            var height = (int)numericUpDownHeight.Value;
            pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(original, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

Думаю, разберётесь.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете изображение тока ставить типа: центр, растянуть по размеру pictureBox, зум. Но чтобы менять картинку, не видел. Есть конечно способ, но там будут появляться полосы прокрутки (*scrollableControl*), иначе никак.

Comment: а через какой элемент можно реализовать такое?